# Default login name for git

Tags: windows, git

How do I set up default login name for git on Windows 7? When I run `git clone ssh://<server>/repo`, git tries to connect to `user@<server>`, where `user` is my Windows username. How can I change the default username for a given server? I cannot use `ssh://<username>@<server>/repo`.

Comment: Why can't you use `ssh://<username>@<server>/repo` or `<user>@<server>:repo` syntax?

Comment: Because that does not help me. I also have submodules on the same server. When I use git and recursive clone, git creates new connections to the same server again with bad username, because the submodule url is without the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ssh connection, you can specify:

- the server
- the name
- the private key

Example:

```
Host server
User yourLogin
Hostname SSH IP address --eg 192.68.24.1
IdentityFile "path to your private ssh key"
```

in a file named `config` (under your `HOME/.ssh`, provided you did defined the `HOME` environment variable, which isn't defined by default in Windows).

See a more complete example in "[nbgit to remote host with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357232/nbgit-to-remote-host-with-ssh/5357423#5357423)".

Comment: I already have the user.name set in the global git config. That does not work.

Comment: @JurajBlaho: sorry, I didn't see the ssh part! I have completely re-edited my answer.

Comment: Where should I set that? I have an `.ssh` directory with `known_hosts` file in it. Where should I set the loginName and private key for the server?

Comment: @JurajBlaho: in that same `.ssh` directory, add a file named '`config`' with your ssh connection. The link I mention illustrates how it works.