# How do I make git fetch ignore my private key?

Tags: linux, ssh, git, cron

I'm writing a cronjob that will `git fetch`. I have a private key that I often use for authenticated git things (like github) which has a passphrase on it, but this specific `git fetch` doesn't need the key. My key is saved in the normal location of `.ssh/id_rsa`. Everything is wonderful when I have an `ssh-agent` running, but my cronjob doesn't have that luxury.

I've tried `GIT_ASKPASS=echo git fetch` but that just fails the passkey and won't fetch the repo.

Comment: It's too bad no one has actually answered this question. Why did you accept VonC's answer since it eas clearly not correct.  The latter part of his response in comments also makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`~/.ssh/config` file](https://superuser.com/a/351098/141) in order to specify a different set of public and private key:

```
Host anEntry
User yourLogin
Hostname SSH IP address --eg 192.68.24.1
IdentityFile "path to your private ssh key without passphrase"
```

You would then use an ssh url like:

```
git fetch anEntry:yourRepo
```

Comment: Can I force it to not use any key since this repo doesn't need one?

Comment: @PaulTarjan Is the url for this repo an ssh one?

Comment: yes, otherwise my cronjob wouldn't be trying my key, right?

Comment: @PaulTarjan then you *need* a public/private (*not* passphrase-protected) key, and you need that public key to be registered in the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.